# How can I add an accurate difference column to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I need to compare numeric data from two datatables with the same schema.
For example two tables with data such as

> PKColumn | numCol | DecimalCol

will end up looking like this after the merge

> PKColumn | numCol 1 | numCol 2 | numCol Diff | DecimalCol 1 | DecimalCol 2 | DecimalCol Diff

Initially, I just created the diff column as an expression col1-col2 but I can end up with unusual looking values

```
col1    col2    diff        c1      c2      diff
12.8    14.6    -1.80000019 33.2    29.8    3.40000153
```

But what I want is:

```
col1    col2    diff        c1      c2      diff
12.8    14.6    -1.8        33.2    29.8    3.4
```

So my current solution is to manually iterate through the rows and set the value using this method:

```
private static void SetDifference(DataRow dataRow, DataColumn numericColumn)
{
    dynamic value1 = dataRow[numericColumn.Ordinal - 2];
    dynamic value2 = dataRow[numericColumn.Ordinal - 1];

    if (IsDbNullOrNullOrEmpty(value1) || IsDbNullOrNullOrEmpty(value2)) return;

    //now find out the most decimals used and round to this value
    string valueAsString = value1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    int numOfDecimals = valueAsString.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Skip(1).Count();

    valueAsString = value2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    numOfDecimals = System.Math.Max(numOfDecimals, valueAsString.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Skip(1).Count());

    double result = Convert.ToDouble(value1 - value2);

    dataRow[numericColumn] = System.Math.Round(result, numOfDecimals);
}
```

But it feels clunky and not good for performance.  Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

**EDIT:** changed column names from "int" to "num" to avoid confusion

**EDIT:** also, I don't always want to round to one decimal spot.  I may have data like numA: 28 numB: 75.7999954 so I want a diff of: -47.7999954

Comment: This is generic data that I receive in the form of a DataSet.  There is no database source for the data.

Comment: How can an int-column be `12.8`?

Comment: That was just to highlight that the columns can be a variety of data types.  I have no problems with the int columns.

Comment: 'Int' usally means that only numbers like `1`, `2`, `3`, `100`, `-77` or `17924` are stored, but certainly not `12.8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have columns that store integer numbers then use an integer number type for them! Probably you used a single precision floating point type. The same holds for decimal types. Use a decimal column type for them and this rounding problem will vanish!

If you use a true decimal type (not float, single, real or double) you will not encounter rounding problems. I do not know which database you are using, but with SQL-Server the correct column type would be `decimal`.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you cannot change the column type, round it to the requested precision like this

```
result = Math.Round((c1-c2) * 10)/10; // One decimal
result = Math.Round((c1-c2) * 100)/100; // Two decimals
result = Math.Round((c1-c2) * 1000)/1000; // Three decimals
```

```
Math.Round(3.141592654 * 10000)/10000  ===>  3.1416
```

--

**UPDATE**

Try this, it should perform well in most cases

```
decimal result = (decimal)col1 - (decimal)col2;
```

Test

```
12.8f - 14.6f  ===>  -1.80000019

(decimal)12.8f - (decimal)14.6f  ===>  -1.8
```

Comment: I'm not using any database.  I receive two reports in the form of DataSets that are created based on some entity data.  I have no control over the data contained in the reports.  I want the difference between numeric data in report1 and numeric data in report2.  Generally, all the data is defined as 'float' but I'd like this to be able to work on any data type.

Comment: I don't want to round, I just want a mathematically correct difference.

Comment: The `float` type has a very limited precision and will give you these rounding errors. Even just storing a value like `1.1` cannot be represented accurately by a `float`, because `1/10` cannot be represented with a finite sequence of `0`s and `1`s with the internal binary representation used.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Olivier's comments I've updated my code to look like this:

```
if(numericColumn.DataType == typeof(int))
{
    dataRow[numericColumn] = System.Math.Abs(value1 - value2);
}
else
{
    dataRow[numericColumn] = Convert.ToDecimal(value1) - Convert.ToDecimal(value2);
}
```

Seems a lot cleaner and it gets the job done.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in sql query using

```
ROUND(table1.IntCol 1 - table2.IntCol 2, 1)
```